# how to sum variables with NA values using withColumn

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame with 4 numeric variables, and i need to create another variable with the sum from the other 4 variables.
This function works, sure:

`df4.withColumn( "sumVariables", sum(df4[x] for x in df4.columns[1:5])).show()`

the problem is the sum with Null values, because the result in a row with

`0|   null|      1|      0` is Null

how can i solve it?

Comment: Just replace null with 0

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
df4.withColumn( "sumVariables", sum(df4[x] for x in df4.columns[1:5] if x != "null") ).show()
```

Comment: Result is the same:
0|   null|      1|      0|   null|

Comment: I didnt notice that `null` is written like that. I changed my answer, if you could give it a try.

Comment: Yes, no problem!! Actually i've have not solution to this issue.
I've been trying given solutions, but there is a problem:
Consider the case: var1: null, var2: null, var3: null, var4: null, result must be null (not is good idea to consider to replace null by ceros).

Answer (score 1):

Replace Null with 0's

```
df4 = df4.fillna(0)
df4.withColumn( "sumVariables", when(sum(df4[x] for x in df4.columns) > 0, sum(df4[x] for x in df4.columns)).otherwise(None)).show()
```

Comment: I have a problem with that solution, because there are some cases with all values Null in the four variables.
by example:
var1: Null, var2: Null, var3: Null, var4: Null. The sum should be Null.

Comment: @JuanDavid : If all values are null in the 4 columns, are you expecting the sum to also be null rather than 0?

Comment: I need to take in mind this cases:
var1: Null, var2: Null, var3: Null, var4: Null. The sum should be Null

Comment: Simplest solution is, if sum is 0, make it null. I can't think of a work around

Comment: Solution is good, but in this case: var1: 0, var2: 0, var3: 0, var4: 0 the sum must be 0, does the function consider this?. I think it is something like "apply" function in R, when you use: apply(matrix(var1,var2,var3,var4),1,function(x) sum(x,na.rm=true)), but i dont know how to execute that on python.